# Break array in multiple arrays based on key value javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, split

I have an array which I would like to split into multiple arrays based on a key(K1 etc key) value (A,AA etc values). My example:

```
array = [{"K1":"A","K2":"B","k3":"AA"},{"K1":"A","K2":"B","k3":"BB"},{"K1":"A","K2":"B","k3":"BB"},{"K1":"A","K2":"B","k3":"CC"}]
```

Should return where values AA, BB, CC are the variables/values for separation. The array is dynamic so ik also could have for example DD, EE etc

```
array 1= [{"K1":"A","K2":"B","k3":"AA"}]
array 2= [{"K1":"A","K2":"B","k3":"BB"},{"K1":"A","K2":"B","k3":"BB"}]
array 3= [{"K1":"A","K2":"B","k3":"CC"}]
```

How do I achieve this

Comment: Please show us what you've already tried.

Comment: As well, it's not quite clear what you mean by 'key value'.

Comment: @AaronChristiansen I would love to but I am new to javascript I have been looking at the split function but ths doenst include a key value

Comment: @JLivengood edited my question

Comment: my guess would be that you are looking for a `groupBy`-function like https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy. But your question is really too unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the keys are in the same order on all the array elements, you can use `reduce` make an object. Convert the object to array using `Object.values`

```js
var array = [{"K1":"A","K2":"B","k3":"AA"},{"K1":"A","K2":"B","k3":"BB"},{"K1":"A","K2":"B","k3":"BB"},{"K1":"A","K2":"B","k3":"CC"}];

[array1,array2,array3] = Object.values(array.reduce((c,v)=>{
 let k = Object.values(v).join("_"); //Using the values as key.
 c[ k ] = c[ k ] || [];
 c[ k ].push( v );
 return c;
},{}))
 
console.log( "array1", array1 );
console.log( "array2", array2 );
console.log( "array3", array3 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Still difficult to decipher what you're actually trying to base the splitting on but heres some general code to help you write/attempt stuff. You can try to loop through the array and push the object to the new split arrays based on normal logic like below

```
// initial array
const array = [{"K1":"A","K2":"B","k3":"AA"},{"K1":"A","K2":"B","k3":"BB"},{"K1":"A","K2":"B","k3":"BB"},{"K1":"A","K2":"B","k3":"CC"}];

// split arrays
const array1 = [];
const array2 = [];
const array3 = [];

array.forEach(obj => {
  // if statements or switch statement depending on how you want to split
  switch(obj.k3) {
    case 'AA':
      array1.push(obj);
      break;
    case 'BB':
      array2.push(obj);
      break;
    case 'CC':
    default:
      array3.push(obj);
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: @J Livengood this seems like a siolution can this be made dynamic depending on a variable lengt of array? Ps. I edited my question with an attempt to make it clearer, sorry im a noob